# Unexpected error during Programmatically adding fragment

Tags: android

I m using this tutorial - [Programmatically add fragment](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/12/programmatically-add-fragment.html)

I did exactly as is in that tutorial, yet find this error-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmentdemo/com.example.fragmentdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           // get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

           //add a fragment
           simpleFragment myFragment = new simpleFragment();
           fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);
           fragmentTransaction.commit();

       }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

public class simpleFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_fragment,container);
        return view;
    }



}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="0px"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="It's TextView in main Activity"
       android:background="#555555"/>
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/myfragment"
       android:layout_width="0px"
       android:layout_weight="4"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="It's Fragment" />
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml and code you are adding two views on same postion

Comment: where is the rest of the code for `simpleFragment`?

Comment: what else do u need? isnt it enough ? I just removed imports..

Comment: possible duplicate of [the specified child already has a parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315567/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent)

Comment: How come that is similar to mine?..strange..same error doesnt mean same problems sometimes, my scenario id different bro

Comment: Could you try `inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_fragment,null)` ?