# Adding Views to a LinearLayout Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have Vertical ScrollView where I am going to add some Views after a buttonClick. Here is the xml of the scroll view

```
<ScrollView
    android:background = "@drawable/border"
    android:layout_weight="31"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutScroll"
        android:padding = "10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >






        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/border_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_width = "fill_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textWord"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/word"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textNumber"
                    android:background = "@drawable/border_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text=" 1 "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/editWord"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textDefinition"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text = "@string/definition" />
            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/editDefinition"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="3"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"/>               
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textEmpty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />





    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In this function I create the same objects for adding them to the LinearLayout

```
private void initInterface (){
    layoutScroll = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.layoutScroll);
    layoutContainer = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());

    textWord = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textDefinition= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textNumber = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textEmpty = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

    editWord = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    editDefinition = new EditText(getApplicationContext());


    layoutContainer.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    layoutContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layoutContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_2);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param1 = 
            new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    layoutContainer.setLayoutParams(param1);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param2 = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(param2);
    textWord.setLayoutParams(param2);
    textWord.setTextAppearance(this,android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    textWord.setText("Word:");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param3= 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams 
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    param3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    param3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    textNumber.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_1);
    textNumber.setTextAppearance(this,android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    textNumber.setLayoutParams(param3);

    relativeLayout.addView(textWord);
    relativeLayout.addView(textNumber);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param4 = param1;
    param4.setMargins(0, 3, 0, 0);
    editWord.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    editWord.setTextAppearance(this,android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    editWord.setLines(1);
    editWord.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    editWord.setLayoutParams(param4);


    textDefinition.setLayoutParams(param1);
    textDefinition.setTextAppearance(this,android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    textDefinition.setText("Definition:");

    editDefinition.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
    editDefinition.setSingleLine(false);
    editDefinition.setLayoutParams(param1);
    editDefinition.setMaxLines(3);
    editDefinition.setLines(3);
    editDefinition.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    editDefinition.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);

    textEmpty.setTextAppearance(this,android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    textEmpty.setLines(1);
    textEmpty.setLayoutParams(param1);

    layoutContainer.addView(relativeLayout);
    layoutContainer.addView(editWord);
    layoutContainer.addView(textDefinition);
    layoutContainer.addView(editDefinition);




}
```

And then I add them to the Layout like this.

```
public void onCLick_Add(View v){
    layoutScroll.addView(layoutContainer);
    layoutScroll.addView(textEmpty);

}
```

The problem is that It only workd once . When I click the button for the second time the app crashes.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does the logcat say?

Comment: I couldn't understand any useful thing from the Log . I haves saved it  you can watch it here 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw1rxewzORCqazl5TEtqeUFCcjg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what is line no 164 in your CreateSetActivity.java

Comment: setting text for a global TexView object
`textNumber.setText(" "+wordCounter+" ");`

Comment: i commented out that line but it is still crashing

Comment: the bug is this : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. Could you post the entire createsetactivity code..

Comment: Here is CreateSetActivity.java code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw1rxewzORCqS09uc3lwNFVVcFE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try calling initInterface() in the onClick_add...for the first time call, it seems all the views are added correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

You are trying to add same layoutContainer and textEmpty multiple times when clicking multiple times. This fails because they are already added and therefore already have a parent. (You cannot add same View to more then one parent)

**Solution**
I guess you want to create a new View every time you press the button and add this to your layoutScroll. You should call your init-method again for every click:

```
public void onCLick_Add(View v){
  initInterface();
  layoutScroll.addView(layoutContainer);
  layoutScroll.addView(textEmpty);
}
```

I would also suggest to divide initInterface() into:

```
private View createLayoutContainer();
private View createTextEmpty();
```

Make sure you take initialization of scrollView outside (e.g. onCreate) and you declare views like layoutContainer localy in the createLayoutContainer() instead of globally.

Here a snippet how it would look:

```
private View createLayoutContainer(){
  LinearLayout layoutContainer = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
  RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());

  TextView textWord = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
  ...
  return layoutContainer;
}

public void onCLick_Add(View v){
  layoutScroll.addView(createLayoutContainer());
  layoutScroll.addView(createTextEmptyView());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs due to the fact that a `ScrollView` can only have on child View. In other words, a `ScrollView` can have a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` or a `TextView` etc. Update your code such that new views inside are added inside `LinearLayout` (**layoutScroll**) instead of `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in the comment, the bug is this : `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Checklist for these kind of bugs.

As pointed out in this post [the specified child already has a parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315567/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent?answertab=active#tab-top)

Double check all your addView calls.

- Make sure not to add any view more then once. When a View is allready
  used (e.g., you got it with findViewById, don't use addView on it.
- When you want to add a view, use addView with a NEW view. You can add
  several of these new views to one view, but you cannot add that one
  view multiple times.
- You can't re-use a view simply by changing some
  stuff. You CAN re-use a variable, but you need to make a new view if
  you want to re-add it using addView.