# Android: Error in adding table layout dynamically

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am trying to dynamically add table layout to an xml file and the LayoutParams are causing errors.

Activity code:

```
package com.pyrospiral.android.tabbedtimetable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TimeTableWeek extends Activity {

TextView subname;
TextView timing;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_table_week);

    //Create text view
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("aaaaa");

    //Layout params
    LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams trparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //Find table in xml
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridtable);
    table.setLayoutParams(params);

    //Create table row

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(trparams);
    row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    row.addView(text);




}

}
```

XML file:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridtable">


    </TableLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pyrospiral.android.tabbedtimetable, PID: 26691
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

Changing TableLayout.LayoutParams to FrameLayout.LayoutParams gives no errors but it also doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change TableLayout to FrameLayout, like this:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

to see your text you have to add the row to the table

```
table.addView(row);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, although if I trying doing that in a loop it says  "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315567/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent?answertab=active#tab-top) answer. The problem is in your code. Maybe you are adding same row multiple time, you need to create new row.

Answer (score 0):

Table's layout parameters are already defined in your XML so I think your variable "params" is unnecessary there.